# Use the previous row for mathematical operation in current line

Tags: bash, awk

I have following sample data:

```
co1 co2 co3
100 200 300
110 230 310
125 235 320
```

I need to perform  below logic on the data:

```
(col2 - col2 of the previous line)/(col1 - col1 of previous line) (col3-col3 of the previous line)/(col1 - col1 of previous line)
```

Which translate to:

```
(230-200)/(110-100) (310-300)/(110-100)
(235-230)/(125-110) (320-310)/(125-110)
```

I tried:

```
cat sample |awk 'NR>1' |'NR>1{f=$1;s=$2;t=$3;next} {print f,s;print $2-s/$1-f,$3-t/$1-f}'
```

Desired output:

```
3   1
0.3 0.6
```

With this logic output would be one less row, as first row would be consumed for second row.

## Error with below data:

```
 104937 20776001011 6893034089
 104937 20776001011 6893034089
 104938 20776062501 6893040119
 104938 20776062501 6893040119
 104938 20776062501 6893040119
 104938 20776062501 6893040119
 104938 20776062501 6893040119
 104939 20776124802 6893047227
 104939 20776124802 6893047227
 104939 20776124802 6893047227
 104939 20776124802 6893047227
 104940 20776178348 6893051452
 104940 20776178348 6893051452
 104940 20776178348 6893051452
 104940 20776178348 6893051452
 104940 20776178348 6893051452
 104941 20776235367 6893055075
 104941 20776235367 6893055075
 104941 20776235367 6893055075
 104941 20776235367 6893055075


61490 6030
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Comment: Is it always 3 lines? of actual lines and 3 columns only?

Comment: No ,there are 100+ line

Comment: cat is useless as the two pipes, after the second pipe command awk is missing, also parentheses because of priority of / over -

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another using awk. Each record is `split` to an array `a` which is used on the next iteration:

```
$ awk 'NR>2{print ($2-a[2])/($1-a[1]),($3-a[3])/($1-a[1])} NR>1{split($0,a)}' file
3 1
0.333333 0.666667
```

Instead of just `print`ing the raw values you can use `printf` to format the output: `printf "%.01f %.01f\n", ...` <s>stolen</s> referred to (and rewarded for :) from @RavinderSingh13's answer... It would output:

```
3.0 1.0
0.3 0.7
```

`%g %g` would output:

```
3 1
0.333333 0.666667
```

Just choose which output type differs least from your preferred.

Comment: Looks much better using `split()`; was trying to get this logic somehow squandered it!

Comment: @Inian I know, _GIF_ rather than TGIF. :D

Comment: got `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted` with real data, how can I add check to this exception ?

Comment: Well, sounds like there is a zero in the divider. which means the same value in two consecutive `$1`s: `$1-a[1]==0`. Question is, what would you like to outpout in that case.

Comment: Is there any way to set a logic to increment it by 1 if they are same, as +1 would not bring change to the data.

Comment: Yeah, replace `($1-a[1])` with `(($1-a[1])+($1-a[1]==0?1:0))`. The latter part means: `if($1-a[1]==0)  then add 1 else add 0`.

Answer (score 5):

an alternative (with paste and awk) for fun:

```
paste file <(tail +2 file)|awk 'NF==6 && NR>1{a=$4-$1;b=$5-$2;c=$6-$3;
                                         printf "%.1f %.1f\n", b/a,c/a}'
```

Comment: got `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted` with `real data`, how can I add check to this exception?

Comment: @monk check if `a` is zero, to do your error handling. E.g.  before printf, do `a=a?a:1` to set `a=1` if `a=0`

Answer (score 4):

@mnok:@try: If your Input_file is same as sample shown file.

```
 awk 'NR>2{printf("%.01f %.01f\n",($2-last_2)/($1-last_1),($3-last_3)/($1-last_1));} NR>1{last_1=$1;last_2=$2;last_3=$3}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Do note that `0.7` in the output of the above result is because of rounding-off to the next higher number and not an incorrect result

Comment: You can use `%g` instead of `%.01f` for slightly better formatting

Comment: got `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=4) fatal: division by zero attempted` with real data, how can I add check to this exception ?

Comment: Are you having any empty line into your Input_file ? If yes then you could add conditions lie NR> && NF and NR>1 && NF to it